Is it possible to get when a DL was used for last time using graph API
Is it possible to figure out in Microsoft office365, what was the last time when a mail/message is delivered to a particular list. What access will be required for this?

Could you include more details like what you tried and where you stuck by editing your question with code and error?


I tried using power Shell for the same, using MessageTrace I'm able to get trace but its for last 10 days only. 2. using Start-HistoricalSearch able to retrieve logs of 90 days for a specific DL only. However if I want to list the last accessed date for the entire organization then this if not feasible. So I want to check if GraphAPI could be used to get the last accessed date of a DL


AFAIK, Microsoft Graph API does not directly provide a way to get the last time a Distribution List (DL) or Mailing List was used or when a message was last delivered to it.


Note that: Microsoft Graph API does not directly provide a way to track the last time a Distribution List (DL) or Mailing List was used or when a message was last delivered to it.


You can use message trace from the Microsoft 365 Defender portal or Compliance Center to get detailed logs of emails sent to a particular DL. This data includes when the emails were delivered.
But it can trace recent period.
You can query for specific actions related to the DL but it requires Audit Log permissions.

Otherwise as an alternate, use Microsoft Graph API allows to query mailboxes and interactions (e.g., through /me/messages or /users/{id}/messages), but this doesn't give direct delivery information to DLs.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages


Try Start-HistoricalSearch command, it can retrieve message trace data up to 90 days. However, this still does not provide direct "last access" time for DLs across the entire organization.
Hence there’s no direct method via Graph API to track the last time a DL was used. You will need to rely on message trace, audit logs, or PowerShell for this information, but each has limitations in terms of the time period they cover.
